# Flink batch data processing

Tags: python, apache-flink

I'm evaluating [Flink](http://flink.apache.org/) for some processing batches of data.  As a simple example say I have 2000 points which I would like to pass through an FIR filter using functionality provided by [scipy](http://www.scipy.org/).  The scipy filter is a simple function which accepts a set of coefficients and the data to filter and returns the data.   Is is possible to create a transformation to handle this in Flink?  It seems Flink transformations are applied on a point by point basis but I may be missing something.

Answer (score 0):

This should certainly be possible. Flink already has a [Python API (beta)](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.0/apis/batch/python.html) you might want to use.

About your second question: Flink can apply a function point by point and can do other stuff, too. It depends what kink of function you are defining. For example, `filter`, `project`, `map`, `flatMap` are applied per record; `max`, `min`, `reduce`, etc. are applied to a group of records (the groups are defined via `groupBy`). There is also the possibility to join data from different dataset using `join`, `cross`, or `cogroup`. Please have a look into the list of available transformations in the documentation: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.0/apis/batch/dataset_transformations.html